# Is there a way to listen for changes in a collection WITHOUT getting back the documents in Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

Suppose I have a collection called `'books'` and a page called "all books" in my app. Now let's say I want a little message to pop up in the top right that says "This list is outdated" every time there is an addition, deletion, or change in my `'books'` collection. Is there any way to achieve this without having the listener send back all the documents in the `'books'` collection each time there is a change? I only want to be *notified* when the data is outdated and nothing else.

If you know how to achieve this please let me know. I'm good with any language but a solution written in Swift will be preferred.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a field `updatedon` to your `books` document and set it to the current time when doing any write (on delete also then, you will have to find a way to hide deleted books).

And set a listener like this:

```
colref.where("updatedon", ">", new Date())
      .orderBy("updatedon","desc")
      .limit(1)
```

This way you are only billed 1 read every time.

Comment: This is indeed what I'd do in this scenario. Note that the query syntax for Swift is slightly different than what you have here: `colref..whereField("updatedon", isGreaterThan: lastupdate).order(by: "updatedon", descending: true).limit(to: 1)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.  A listener on a document or collection always receives the entire document that changed.

If you want a "lite" notification, you could try to use FCM to send a message to the client when a document of interest has changed, but then you'll have to keep a record on the backend of every interesting document for every user, check that list with every change using a Cloud Functions trigger, then notify each client of each interesting change.  This is not at all the same as a listener, and would be a lot of work.